# V-for only showing one of two JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I'm doing a v-for passing two JSON objects, but I'm not able to show all the values on screen, in my case, only first object is called.
My JSON data is locally on external .json file, not getting by API.

```
        <b-card-body v-for="municipio in municipios.centro_oeste.rio_vermelho,municipios.centro_oeste.:key="index">
    <b-card-text>{{ municipio.title }}</b-card-text>
        </b-card-body>  
Using (obj1,obj2) in v-for only shows obj1...
```

JSON:

```
{
  "centro_oeste": {
    "rio_vermelho": [
      {"title": "Goiás"},
      {"title": "Araguapaz"},
      {"title": "Aruanã"},
      {"title": "Britânia"},
      {"title": "Faina"},
      {"title": "Guaraita"},
      {"title": "Heitoraí"},
      {"title": "Itaberaí"},
     {"title": "Itapirapuã"},
      { "title": "Itapuranga"},
      { "title": "Jussara"},
      { "title": "Matrinchã"},
      { "title": "Mossâmedes"},
      { "title": "Mozarlãndia"},
      { "title": "Nova Crixas"},
      { "title": "St° Fé de Goiás"}
    ],
    "oeste_1": [
      {"title": "Amorinópolis"},
      {"title": "Aragarças"},
      {"title": "Arenópolis"},
      {"title": "Baliza"},
      {"title": "Bom Jardim de Goiás"},
      {"title": "Diorama"},
      {"title": "Fazenda Nova"},
      {"title": "Iporá"},
      {"title": "Israelândia"},
      { "title": "Ivolãndia"},
      { "title": "Jaupaci"},
      { "title": "Moiporá"},
      { "title": "Montes Claros de Goiás"},
      { "title": "Piranhas"}
    ]
}
```

obj1+obj doesn't work as well!
What I do to join this two objs?!

Comment: You can [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the two arrays, or use the spread operator: `[...arrayA, ...arrayB]` (always try to break down the issue into small parts: this isn't about v-for or Vue or JSON, it's about joining two arrays; find the simplest problem and you will find existing answers aplenty)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define the `index` before using it. You can use the `spread operator` to join the two lists. A `computed` property would make it more organized:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    municipios: {
      "centro_oeste": {
        "rio_vermelho": [ {"title": "Goiás"}, {"title": "Araguapaz"} ],
        "oeste_1": [ {"title": "Amorinópolis"}, {"title": "Aragarças"} ]
      }  
    } 
  }),
  computed: {
    centro_oeste_list: function() {
      return [...this.municipios.centro_oeste.rio_vermelho, ...this.municipios.centro_oeste.oeste_1];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div
    v-for="(municipio, index) in centro_oeste_list"
    :key="index"
  >
    <p>{{ municipio.title }}</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```